# Why can't I get 3 webcam to run in parallel with pthreads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, pthreads

I need some help with OpenCV with threading using C++. I am using a raspberry pi 3B. Which is a quad core. There are 4 USB 2.0 devices, 3 USB 2.0 webcam and USB 2.0 Arduino. The webcam’s cable has been spliced out to provide voltage on its own, so only data wires are going into the pi. The Arduino is being powered by the pi.
Now to the issue. I have 4 threads going, 3 for the webcams and 1 for the Arduino. The webcams wait for the Arduino to send a signal to the webcams in parallel. The issue is, I cannot get the 3 cameras to work simultaneously. I can get any combination of 2 cameras to work but not 3. When I try 3 webcams, I get an error of empty frames.

[Link To Webcam Used](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CWSYAY4)

I tried with no success:

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80
```

```
[ WARN:2] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (1004) tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout.
Empty Frame
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.3.0) /home/pi/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:738: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Aborted
```

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<thread>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>

    #include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include"pthread.h"
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string>
    #include<boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

    #include<mutex>
    #include<condition_variable>
    #include<atomic>


    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable suspend_cv;
    std::atomic<bool> enabled (false);

    struct args {
        int camNum;
        char* camName;
        int x;
        int y;
        };


    void* camSetup(void *inputs){
    cv::VideoCapture stream(((struct args*)inputs)->camNum);
    cv::Mat Frame;
    //cv::Mat resizeFrame;
    if(!stream.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Cannot Open Camera: " + ((struct args*) inputs)->camNum + '\n';
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Camera Open: " << ((struct args*) inputs)->camNum + '\n';
    }
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while (true){
        stream >> Frame;
        //cv::resize(Frame, resizeFrame, cv::Size(25, 25));
        while (enabled){
            // Get current time from the clock, using microseconds resolution
            const boost::posix_time::ptime now = 
                boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

            // Get the time offset in current day
            const boost::posix_time::time_duration td = now.time_of_day();
            const long year         = now.date().year();
            const long month        = now.date().month();
            const long day          = now.date().day();
            const long hours        = td.hours();
            const long minutes      = td.minutes();
            const long seconds      = td.seconds();
            const long milliseconds = td.total_milliseconds() -
                                      ((hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000);

            char buf[80];
            sprintf(buf, "%02ld%02ld%02ld_%02ld%02ld%02ld__%03ld", 
                year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
                std::string sBuf = buf;
                std::string PATH = std::string("/home/pi/Desktop/") +
                                ((struct args*)inputs)->camName + 
                                    '/' +
                                    std::string(((struct args*)inputs)->camName) +
                                    '_' +
                                    sBuf +
                                    ".jpeg";
            if (Frame.empty())
            {
                std::cout << "Empty Frame" <<std::endl;
                stream >> Frame;
                //cv::resize(Frame, resizeFrame, cv::Size(25, 25));

            }
            cv::imwrite(PATH, Frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0){
                break;
            }
            suspend_cv.wait(lock);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
    }


    void* ardReader(void*){
    ARDUINO STUFF HAPPENS…
    }

    int main(){
    struct args *cameraA = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    struct args *cameraB = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    struct args *cameraC = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));

    cameraA->camNum = 0;
    char camA[] = "camA";
    cameraA->camName = camA;
    cameraA->x = 100;
    cameraA->y =100;

    cameraB->camNum = 2;
    char camB[] = "camB";
    cameraB->camName = camB;
    cameraB->x = 100;
    cameraB->y = 300;

    cameraC->camNum = 4;
    char camC[] = "camC";
    cameraC->camName = camC;
    cameraC->x = 100;
    cameraC->y = 500;

    pthread_t t1, t2, t3, t4;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, camSetup, (void *) cameraA);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, camSetup, (void *) cameraB);
    pthread_create(&t3, NULL, camSetup, (void *) cameraC);
    pthread_create(&t4, NULL, ardReader, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    pthread_join(t3, NULL);
    pthread_join(t4, NULL);
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that a difference in 20mS made a big enough difference for threading/opencv. To answer my own question in case someone comes across this issue again, change the waitkey time to the following...

#### Incorrect for threading in this case

```
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0){
            break;
        }
```

#### Correct for threading in this case

```
        if (cv::waitKey(10) == 27){
            break;
        }
```

I also move the `cv::waitKey` to the main thread.
Though I still had the errors this did prove to work at times.

One last thing I did was open and close the camera every time I needed to grab an image. This allowed me to get a frame guaranteed every time, this is slower but it always worked.

Comment: The timeout is not about the multithreading, this is about USB bandwidth high consume. Depending on the resolution and FPS you will hit the very low limits on RPI3.